# Como fazer um programa em python capaz de executar o comando ifconfig e que exiba na tela o seu resultado?

Tags: python

Bom dia!!!

Preciso fazer um programa em python capaz de executar o comando ipconfig e que exiba na tela o seu resultado. Alguem sabe como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, para alcançar o resultado desejado, basta utilizar o módulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Segue um exemplo:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ifconfig"])
```

ifconfig é um comando do linux que lista as interfaces de rede.

Para utilizar no windows basta substituir o `ifconfig` por `ipconfig`.